# styled-components does not style <hr /> element

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I am trying to make a line but styled-components gives an error and the whole page doesn't render.

Here's the code

```js
//using styled-components

export const Line = styled.hr`
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  marginleft: -100;
`;
```

This is the screenshot of error shown in the browser's console.
[image: error shown in the browser's console]

Comment: How are you using `<Line />`?

Comment: I am using just the way you wrote it but turns out when I restarted the app it started working fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tag hr can not have children. U can use hr with styled-components in case it doesn't children.
U just use it like this: `<Line />`
Not like this: `<Line>Hello</Line>`
Your code Line must like this:

```
const Line = styled.hr`
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  margin-left: -100px;
`;
```

See the code sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/qxqzzko8oq